# How to use SpEL expression on Spring Data Mongodb?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am not able to figure-out how to use SpEL expression to my existing query and document for a newly introduced field.

Example :

```
@Document(collection = "abc")
public class Abc {

 private boolean deleted;
 public boolean isDeleted() {
  return deleted;
 }

 public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
  this.deleted = deleted;
 }

}
```

I am already using Spring Data Mongodb

```
@Repository
public interface AbcRepository extends MongoRepository < Abc, String > {

 Abc findAllByDeleted(boolean deleted);

}
```

Note: I have almost 1000+ documents on abc collection.

I wanted to introduce new field for example status on my collection and my query is going to change and it will not return me anything because the new field is **not exists** with old data , how do I handle this scenario ? I don't want to do data-patch. So i found we can use exists from spring data SpEL expression.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.M3/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-spel

Here are my changes :

```
@Document(collection = "abc")
public class Abc {
...
...

private boolean status;
 public boolean isStatus() {
  return status;
 }

 public void setStatus(boolean status) {
  this.status = status;
 }
}
```

and my query changes to

```
//Tried this but throwing exception
@Query("{'status' : {$exists :false}}")
Abc findAllByDeletedAndStatus(boolean deleted, boolean status);
```

How can use SpEL Expressions to check if status field is exists and apply the parameter passed from caller?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to fully understand your request, but see bellow a bit of help.

Assuming `Abc` has `deleted` and `status` attributes :

```
@Query("{ $and :[" +
          "?#{ { 'deleted' : [0] } }," +
          "?#{ { 'status' : [0] } }" +
         "]}")
  Abc findAllByDeletedAndStatus(boolean deleted, boolean status);
```

If your params are optional, you could use this way (which is very useful in case of optionals filters):

```
  @Query("{ $and :[" +
          "?#{ [0] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'deleted' : [0] } }," +
          "?#{ [1] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'status' : [1] } }" +
       "]}")
  Abc findAllByDeletedAndStatus(boolean deleted, boolean status);
```